# Cannot find local variable "bv" Trying to turn my json file into objects

Tags: android, jackson

I am new to Android Java. I have an error of "cannot find the local variable vs".  Did I do something wrong?  I cannot make my json file into objects...Please help.  Thanks.

```
The following is my json file.

    "bv": [
        {
            "topic": "topic1",
            "vs": [
                    {
                            "idnum": "1",
                            "vn": "vn1",
                            "v": "v1 sentence"

                     },

                     {
                            "idnum": "2",
                            "vn": "vn2",
                            "v": "v2 sentence"

                     }

                       ]
         },
         {
            "topic": "topic2",
           "vs": [
                       {
                             "idnum": "3",
                              "vn": "vn3",
                              "v": "v3 sentence"

                       },

                       {
                              "idnum": "4",
                              "vn": "vn4",
                              "v": "v4 sentence",


                       }

                      ]

        }

]
}
```

And the class as follow:

```
    public class BV {

    String topic;
    ArrayList <VS> vs;

    public String gettopic() {
        return topic;
    }
    public void settopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }


}

    public class VS {


        private String idnum;
        private String vn;
        private String v;



        public void setidnum(String idnum) {
            this.idnum = idnum;
        }

        public String getidnum() {
            return idnum;
        }

        public String getVn() {

            return vn;
        }

        public void setVn(String vn) {

            this.vn = vn;
        }

        public String getV() {
            return v;
        }
        public void setV(String v) {
            this.v = v;
        }


}
```

And the following is my main class.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String jsonFile = loadJSONFromAsset();

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            BV bv = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, BV.class);

            System.out.println("BV.topic = " + bv.topic);

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("data.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a getter for the `Arraylist` in the `BV` class :

```
public ArrayList<VS> getVs() {
    return vs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I still get the "cannot find the local variable message".  Did I miss any other declaration or there is a problem in my gradle(just added).  Thanks.